# Javascript Remove Class On Scroll

Tags: javascript

I made a script to add a class named `anotherclass` to `.section-3` once the scroll is past `.section-2`.

However now I am trying to remove class from `#section-3` once it scrolls back up and over `.section-2` or even `.section-1`.

```js
window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
  var elementTarget = document.querySelector('.section-2');
  if (window.scrollY > (elementTarget.offsetTop + elementTarget.offsetHeight)) {
    document.querySelector('.section-3').classList.add('anotherclass');
  }
});
```

```css
.section-0 {
  height: 1100px;
  width: 100%;
  background: purple;
}

.section-1 {
  height: 800px;
  width: 100%;
  background: green;
}

.section-3 {
  height: 1800px;
  width: 100%;
  background: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="section-0"></div>
<div class="section-1"></div>
<div class="section-2">Scroll past this div</div>
<div class="section-3"></div>
```

Codepen: https://codepen.io/MistaPrime/pen/XWWYeBZ

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want a solution that covers just that one element, rather than something more general, you can just add an `else` clause to your existing event listener and call `classList.remove`:

```js
window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
  var elementTarget = document.querySelector('.section-2');
  if (window.scrollY > (elementTarget.offsetTop + elementTarget.offsetHeight)) {
      document.querySelector('.section-3').classList.add('anotherclass');
  } else {
      document.querySelector('.section-3').classList.remove('anotherclass');
  }
});
```

Comment: I think this will work. I like it as it is so simple. I am just wondering what if I need to remove the class when it scrolls back past `.section-1`. Any idea how it would work?

Comment: Are you looking for something like `inViewport` kind of behavior? I.E. Add an `active` class to the current `div` in the current viewport

Comment: @dev_junwen Yes, I think `inViewport` may work. I could remove `.anotherclass` once `.section-1` is visible in viewport again.

Comment: I'll write an example for you when I have time using the `inViewport` kind of behaviour.